# How to get rid of Status.Unavailable in a callbackFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have this code to get internet connection status:

```
override fun getStatus() = callbackFlow {
    val callbackFlow = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            trySend(Status.Available)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            trySend(Staus.Lost)
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            trySend(Status.Unavailable)
        }
    }
    manager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callbackFlow)
    awaitClose {
        manager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callbackFlow)
    }
}.distinctUntilChanged()
```

I call din function from the ViewModel class:

```
fun getStatus() = repo.getStatus()
```

And inside the activity I have:

```
val status = viewModel.getStatus().collectAsState(
    initial = Status.Unavailable
).value
Text(
    text = "$status"
)
```

The problem is when I start the app, when I'm connected, for a short period of time I get `Unavailable` and right after that `Available`. How to get rid of `Unavailable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ConnectivityManager takes some time to determine the current connection state, so the `callbackFlow` won't produce a value immediately. In your composable, however, the state object (retrieved by `collectAsState`) needs a value right away, even when the flow hasn't had enough time yet to produce a value. That's why you have to provide the `initial` value to that function. That value will be taken until the flow produces its first value. You set that value to `Staus.Unavailable` (shouldn't it be `Status` instead of `Staus`?), so even when your device is connected, it is first displayed as `Unavailable` until the actual `Available` connectivity can be determined.

Just change the value for `initial` to whatever you want to be displayed until the connectivity status could be determined. It can be useful to define a new status `Unknown` or something similar to differentiate it from the other status values.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way I can get rod of the initial value? Even if I set "Unknown" doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Think about it: When your UI is displayed, a value is needed. The flow doesn't *have* a value yet, though. So there *must* be an initial value that can be taken instead, it obviouly cannot be any different. And yes, "Unknown" *does* solve your problem. Why wouldn't it? It's the truth after all, the connectivity status *is* unknown at that point, so there is no problem there, everything is as it should be.